# How to add new table and column by form input

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to add New table in my database and this table should have 5 columns but it should be done by filling up a form in the website [image: form] Let's say I'm going to add Travel Order table with it's five columns. Now i have this code in my form and it gives me this error: Call to undefined method mysqli::mysqli_real_escape_string()

`<input type="text" class="form-control1" onKeyPress= "return lettersOnly(event)" name= "categoryname" id="categoryname" placeholder="Category Name..." maxlength="30" reqiured>` this for the table name.

`<input type="text" class="form-control1" onKeyPress= "return lettersOnly(event)" name="firstattrib" id="firstattrib" placeholder="..." maxlength="30">` this for one of the column. (please don't mind my naming of variables)

`

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","doctrack_db");

```
// Check connection
if ($connect->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connect->connect_error);
} 

// sql to create table
$sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$categoryname." (
            id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,  
            file LONGBLOB(30) NOT NULL,
        )";

$firstattrib = $connect->mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['firstattrib']);

//query to add columns to table
$query = 'ALTER TABLE ' .$categoryname . ' 
                ADD COLUMN '. $firstattrib .' VARCHAR(30) TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\' AFTER file';
```

if ($connect->query($sql)&$connect->query($query) === TRUE) {
        echo "alert('Category created successfully!!')";
    } else {
        echo "alert('Error creating Category!!')" . $connect->error;
    }

$connect->close();
?>`

Can you please tell me which part i got wrong or is it wrong as a whole?

Comment: table being newly made makes no difference. What is your error?

Comment: have you executed that $sql1 query?

Comment: @Ern can you explain why you can't?

Comment: What is the error...Post the error you got

Comment: Let me explain it further. In my website, I have to add a new category, let's say "Travel Order Category". So in my database it should also add a new table named "Travel Order". But I created the table using PHP and not directly in phpMyAdmin. So when I add a new Document in "Travel Order Category", I can't use this code `$sql = "INSERT INTO travelorder (travelername, destination, date)` since "travelorder" table is just newly added. Now you see, the website I'm attempting to develop can add as many category as you want.

Comment: your table name is "Travel Order" & you tried the sql `$sql = "INSERT INTO travelorder (travelername, destination, date)` it must give error. update the table name to 'travelorder'

Comment: It's probably better to [edit] your question and add the clarifications/explinations instead of adding them in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    <?php
    // Create connection
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","","test") OR die("Server Connection error");
    mysql_select_db("test") OR die("DB error");

    $category = "category"; 

    // sql to create table
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE ".$category." (
        id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
        firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        email VARCHAR(50),
        reg_date TIMESTAMP
    )";

    if(mysql_query($sql)){
        $sql1 = "INSERT INTO ".$category." (firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES ('John', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";
        mysql_query($sql1);
    }
?>
```

and it doesn't matter when you create table, what matter is when you inserting data into table have to has exist.

Comment: Let me explain it further. In my website, I have to add a new category, let's say "Travel Order Category". So in my database it should also add a new table named "Travel Order". But I created the table using PHP and not directly in phpMyAdmin. So when I add a new Document in "Travel Order Category", I can't use this code $sql = "INSERT INTO travelorder (travelername, destination, date) since "travelorder" table is just newly added. Now you see, the website I'm attempting to develop can add as many category as you want. – Ern 11 mins ago

Comment: okay i got, so you are saying that 1st you are adding category and then its data, simply you can take category into a variable and then pass it to sql query. see i updated my answer